# Where can I find examples of fuzzy logic applications in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, spatial-analyst

The last ArcGIS version (10) includes two arctoolbox tools for [fuzzy logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) ([Fuzzy Membership](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000rn000000.htm), and [Fuzzy Overlay](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000rp000000.htm)). Does anyone know where can I find some examples showing how they can be applied?

[image]

*(From [Desktop 10 help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Applying_fuzzy_logic_to_overlay_rasters/009z000000rv000000/).)*

Comment: is there a tool, fuzzy logic, in argis 9.3?

Comment: @giovanni I believe not, if memory serves.  In support of this, check out the [What's new in ArcGIS SA 10 page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00qp0000001n000000.htm).

Answer (score 6):

There's a video example from an esri conference here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hd13H0XO0LU

Answer (score 3):

A very good article from esri for ArcGis and Fuzzy logic. With a good example and some bibliography.

[Incorporating Expert Knowledge -
New fuzzy logic tools in ArcGIS 10](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0410/fuzzylogic.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is a dissertation on:

*Watershed water quality modeling using integrated **fuzzy modeling approach** with HSPF model and radar rainfall data*
Author: Madhusudhan Narayana

"Watershed water quality modeling is very essential for watershed management activities. These modeling activities and resulting simulations were used as the main resource for several decision making processes. In this research study, uncertainties associated with **the watershed water quality modeling were handled with fuzzy modeling approach in three different phases**"

http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/dissertations/AAI1493730/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are very few examples of fuzzy logic using ArcGIS 10 on the internet. Youtube will show you this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hd13H0XO0LU about bald eagle habitat.

Fuzzy logic can be used in all kinds of different scenarios from mineral exploration, site selection, basically anything that has multiple inputs that each meet a criteria.  In site selection you may use slope, distance from water, distance from roads, etc and put it into a fuzzy logic model.  Selection of membership will mostly be linear but you can play with those classifications to get a better idea of how they work. The fuzzy membership plays into the fuzzy overlay in how you combine layers with AND, OR, GAMMA (mostly AND/OR).  ESRI has a site selection tutorial for $30 which shows how the above youtube video is applied.