# How to find boundaries with Fuzzy logic and GIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fuzzy-logic

How can I use Fuzzy logic in order to find the boundaries of an area with points? Is there a GIS software that does it? I would prefer Arcgis.

example from scholar pedia

[image]

Figure 1: Bird's-eye view on a forest: Where is the boundary of the forest? Which location is in the forest and which is out of it? (image from: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Fuzzy_sets#example)

Comment: Here's a fuzzy logic demo in ArcGIS 10: http://downloads2.esri.com/campus/blog/demos/EsriFuzzyLogicDemo.mp4

Comment: Related: [Where can I find examples of fuzzy logic applications in ArcGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13753/where-can-i-find-examples-of-fuzzy-logic-applications-in-arcgis)

Comment: Do your point data represent individual tree locations?  Are there additional metrics associated with the xy locations, such as canopy diameter?

Comment: If these data are a census of tree locations, fuzzy logic would be an inappropriate choice of analysis methods.  Rather, I would recommend a vector based delineation.

Comment: I worked on a similar project - creating oil & gas field boundaries from well point locations. [GIS-Automated Oil and Gas Field Boundaries](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/15420350802142652?journalCode=wmgl20)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple technique to implement, no fuzzy logic required:
Buffer all Points
Merge or Union all Buffers
Dissolve
Delete Outlier Polygons where Area < certain value, producing the Forest Outline
You can Intersect the original Points with the Polygon Outline to detemine Points within the Outline.

Comment: How do you decide what buffer distance?

Comment: @Kirk, I would experiment using different buffer distances. BTW, the ArcGIS Union tool has a nice Gap feature, specify NO_GAPS, there will be no inner gaps in the polygons. I've seen this buffer & dissolve technique used several ways to produce Oil/Gas Well Field outlines from Well locations.